# On add existing item in VS2010, why can't I "add as link" a file from the same project?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I have two folders in my library project, folder A and folder B. Folder A will contain all the real files, but Folder B (and a bunch of other folders) need to contain links to the folder A files.

I tried going Add existing item (go to folder A)-> add (down arrow) -> add as link but the add existing item dialog window just closes and nothing happens. It seems I can add links to files outside the library project though. What's going on here?

-Isaac

Comment: Can you explain why you need those items twice? What are those items? I'm sure there is a solution that works with having each item only once (Actually, in my opinion, it makes no sense at all to have an item and both a link to that item within the same project).

Comment: Well, Folder A will have a LOT of files in it. Hundreds. It's in a library project that serves a bunch of different front end projects. For each different front end, I want to have a different folder that contains the folder A files that are relevant to it. That way I don't have to scroll through the hundreds of files in folder A to find what I want. If it could be a link, then I just click on it and it opens the right folder A file. Also I'm hoping I can use code to get all the file names in the shortcuts folder to feed as a configuration parameter.

Comment: There is no real use case for the feature you want as everything can be done when an item is added *once* so a project in Visual Studio. It looks to me as if you were trying to achieve something which could be done a lot simpler, e.g. by restructuring your files, by using a pre/post-build step or a custom MS Build task. Can you please describe in detail what you are trying to achieve so that we can find a more standard solution for you?

Comment: It's alright, I can do without this feature. I have other solutions up my sleeve but they're just not as nice as this would have been. Anyways, thanks for your help!

Comment: I think it is a valid use case.  For example, I am building a web project which contains multiple independent 'sites' (site.com/foo, site.com/bar) for example.  I'd like to keep common files in a single folder in source control, but reference them as links from each of the sites.  The main benefit here is the copy local attribute, which would copy the common file to the correct output folder at build time.

Answer (score 8):

For some reason Visual Studio seems to silently ignore possible problems with adding file as a link. I just had the same problem and the solution was to:

1. Check if project folder already contains a file with the name of file being linked, if so delete or rename this resource.
2. Visual Studio 2010 seems to cache project directory contents, as (1) was not enough to successfully link the file. Restarting VS helps.

Comment: Instead of restarting Visual Studio, a project can be unloaded and reloaded again.

Answer (score 0):

Sound like Visual Studio is crashing for some reason.  I just tested this in project that has many folders.  I had an images folder and I was able to add as link and image to another folder, so it seems it is possible.

Comment: there's no crash, it just doesn't add anything.

Answer (score 0):

It does add the file to the project but does so to the original location, not the new location.

You can see this if you exclude the original file from your VS project (but don't delete the file from disk) - the file will then get add to your project in it's original location

e.g. if you have folder `FolderA\index.htm` and `FolderB`, and you want to create a link to `index.htm` in `FolderB`.  Exclude `index.htm` from your project (but leave it in `FolderA` on the disk) so your project just has two empty folders.  Right-click on `FolderB` and click  `Add Existing Item`, select `index.htm` from `FolderA` and click `Add as Link`.  The file will be added to your project but under `FolderA` (where it resides on disk) not within `FolderB` which is where you told it to add it.

So looks like a VS bug to me.

As has been mentioned, this is a valid scenario if you have multiple "root" websites within one project but you want to share resources between them

Answer (score 0):

In my case (using Visual Studio 2013) I just had to show all files (button on the top of the Solution Explorer), right click on each file/folder and click on "Include on Project".